# SharePoint Team Pages Shared List

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, team-sites

I have multiple team sites, some with their own sub sites. Is there a way to have shared sharepoint lists between them? Say if I wanted the Manufacturing team subsites to have shared list between upstream and downstream called subject matter experts where they both could add in items to the list and it would show up on both of their subsites respectively? Or another way, Have a Continous Improvement list residing on the CI Team site that exists entirely outside of the Manufacturing site structure but they still can add items to it on their end without having to navigate to the CI Team site?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is this is not possible.  What I would suggest doing is If you have a list in Site A, and Site B users need to access the list in Site A, create a link on Site B that points to the Site A list, then give permissions to the Site B users to the Site A list.  Your users are changing sites but they won't really notice.  You could also use workflows to kept the two lists "synced" but that would definitely be more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Shared list is not supported in SharePoint.

One common workaround is to use SharePoint designer workflow or Microsoft Flow to update contents between lists.

Here are some references for you.

[Copy data between two SharePoint lists (or any two data sources) efficiently.](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/copying-using-filtering/)

[How to use Flow to copy items between two data sources.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4467880/how-to-copy-items-between-two-sharepoint-lists-by-using-flow)

[SHAREPOINT LIST WORKFLOW: CREATE OR UPDATE LIST ITEM ON ANOTHER SHAREPOINT SITE LIST.](https://www.advaiya.com/blog/sharepoint-list-workflow-create-or-update-list-item-on-another-sharepoint-site-list/)